# How do I make a dynamic object type that autocompletes?

Tags: typescript

Basically, I want to end up with something like this:

```
const counter = createModel<number>({
  state: 0,
  actions: {
    incrementBy: (state, amount) => state + amount
  }
})
```

With the following constraints:

1. The input for `createModel` enforces the value of each `action` to be a reducer function (i.e. takes in a state and returns a new state)
2. When I start typing `model.actions.incrementBy`, TypeScript knows that the `incrementBy` method exists and knows the type of its arguments

**How would I achieve this?**

This is what I've tried so far:

```
interface Action<S, P = unknown> {
  (state: S, payload: P): S;
}

type ActionMap<S> = Record<string, Action<S>>;

type ModelConfig<S, A extends ActionMap<S> = ActionMap<S>> = {
  state: S;
  actions: A;
};

// usage example

const counter: ModelConfig<number> = {
  state: 0,
  actions: {
    incrementBy: (state, amount: number) => state + amount,
  },
};
```

but this doesn't work... I suspect that `Record<string, Action<S>>` prevents TypeScript from knowing that `config.actions.incrementBy` exists.

The closest I've gotten is this:

```
type ActionMap<S, M extends Record<string, Action<S, unknown>>> = {
  [K in keyof M]: M[K];
};

type ModelConfig<S, A extends ActionMap<S>> = {
  state: S;
  actions: A;
};

// usage example

type CounterActions = {
  incrementBy: Action<number, number>;
};

const counter: ModelConfig<number, CounterActions> = {
  state: 0,
  actions: {
    incrementBy: (state, amount: number) => state + amount,
  },
};
```

But I really want to find a way to avoid needing to explicitly define `CounterActions`. Any thoughts? I really want to believe this is possible...

Comment: You can't use an explicit type annotation or else that will lose the type information in the object you assign it to. You need a helper function to infer these types for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the desired reduction in typing by using a constrained identity function when creating your models. Here's an example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQWTgEzQBtEAeAZQD4AKASgC4yAVRNAD2zHwGdEBvAFCJE3KFjSNyAbiGIM0eGG6MASmghwU+UqJQwwAcwA0iaqPGSTAOhvpRjDGACeAbQC6tRAF5KiKjIBfGgBbAmJGJk8fRBZBYXQoEBQkUMISaNTiQIEBDSUoZDhwbBRvZHRxPDTSMBBggCM0FBpaajjEAHoOxAA5OFgINEQoAAsh-CL6oiH9ADc4CCxFYQA9NdlzbEYABiNZeVgEZX5ZYX1UNGC0MCgAISdGMzFsEwxQ4sZahqao302hgDUcneNz2wmEhAuVxu90e-1eIKgnzqjRQvxEzyGAFpgUVQbIAnsArQZAIoE4AA5DADCeJKAEEFAgem8hl5EABrNBOODAYaUtC8wrFJpWA6KbhSTrdABE53Q0LuThliAAPogZZCFdclTKchoRSgrP8pV1EF9Ubk6aLxUcrPLLjr7qbuk8LOaUU0EXTkd80d5fBamlbDWKmUorFrHTCnC7TP9fajvR8PX70UGUAIgA)

```ts
function createModel <S>(): <T extends {
  state: S;
  actions: Record<string, (state: S, ...rest: any[]) => S>;
}>(model: T) => T {
  return model => model;
}

const counter = createModel<number>()({
  // Notice the double invocation  ^^^
  state: 0,
  actions: {
    incrementBy: (state, amount: number) => state + amount,
    decrementBy: (state, amount: number) => state - amount,
  },
});

type CounterActionName = keyof typeof counter.actions; // "incrementBy" | "decrementBy"

counter.state; // number
counter.actions.incrementBy; // (state: number, amount: number) => number
counter.actions.decrementBy; // (state: number, amount: number) => number
```